# CFG for L={a^i b^j c^i; i,j > 0}

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I worked a bit on this and got this-:

```
S->ABC
A->aA/a
B->bB/b
C->cC/c
```

The obvious problem here is I am unable to count number of a's and c's which should be equal. How do I create a cfg that can count a and c's and make them equal? Please guide.

If this was $a^i b^i c^j$ I could make a cfg.

Answer (score 2):

So I worked a bit. And I think I got the answer. Feel free to correct me.

```
S -> aSc | aXc
X -> bX | b
```

It works a bit, e.g.: `aaaabcccc` gets derivation done. Similarly it works for `aabbbcc` as well.

Comment: This is correct, good work!